# How can you check if the user's browser supports Google Caja?

Tags: google-caja

I'm using Google Caja to sanitize user input on my site. I'm currently processing the user's input inside the callback I pass to caja.whenReady(). However, on Microsoft Edge, the callback is never called because Edge can't be made safe by Caja. In the event that Caja doesn't work, I want to fall back to processing the user's content server side where I'll simply strip out all JavaScript.

How can I check if Caja works with the user's browser?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will give you a function, `browserSupportsCaja()` that will return true at any time after Caja calls its `whenReady()` callbacks. This way you can determine if Caja is supported after it initializes.

If you check for Caja support before it finishes initializing, then you will get a false negative. To catch that, just put the code that you want to execute after Caja is ready in a `whenReady()` callback and assume that Caja is not available anywhere else.

```
caja.initialize({
  cajaServer: 'https://caja.appspot.com/'
});

function browserSupportsCaja() {
  return browserSupportsCaja.return_value;
}
browserSupportsCaja.return_value = false;

caja.whenReady( function() {
  browserSupportsCaja.return_value = true;
});
```